# How to make a clickable map in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've done this with Flash and Actionscript but does anyone know how I'd even begin to make a clickable map in iOS?

Is using cocos2d a good approach?

I want to make a clickable map of countries into a mini-game.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know you can create iOS applications utilizing Flash 5.5?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Some other good resources:

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=116

Just some food for thought.

I have done a few simple things thus far like Rss readers with no issues. Never done a large game.